# php preg_match and ereg syntax difference

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, deprecated, ereg

I found that syntax of `preg_match()` and the deprecated `ereg()` is different.
For example:

I thought that

```
preg_match('/^<div>(.*)</div>$/', $content);
```

means the same as

```
ereg('^<div>(.*)</div>$', $content);
```

but I was wrong. `preg_match()` doesn't include special characters as enter like `ereg()` does.

So I started to use this syntax:

```
preg_match('/^<div>([^<]*)</div>$/', $content);
```

but it isn't exactly the same to what I need.

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem, without using deprecated functions?

Comment: My suggestion is to use xml parser to work with HTML code instead of regex.

Comment: Reason is that preg is the Perl Compatible Regex library, ereg is the POSIX complient regex library. What exactly does not work?

Comment: You use / as delimiter so you have to escape all / chars with \. Ex: `/^<div>(.*)<\/div>$/`

Comment: You can use something other than / to escape. Ex: `@^<div>(.*)</div>@`

Comment: my problem is that ereg('^anything.*anything$', 'anything1234<enter>12345anything'); returns TRUE..... and preg_match('/^anything.*anything$/', 'anything1234<enter>12345anything'); returns FALSE; ("<enter>" means special character for enter pressing...) i need functionality of ereg make with non deprecated php functions...

Comment: sorry but preg_match('/^anything.*anything$/', 'anything1234<enter>12345anything'); return true.

Comment: it doesn't :)... in my case <enter> represents special enter character.. can you understand me? I can't make enter char in this bloody comment window :)

Comment: Ok but the dot take all characters, maybe it's multiple lines ? Try to add the "m" modifier like this : preg_match('/^anything.*anything$/m', 'anything1234<enter>12345anything') or try also with "s" modifier.

Comment: Oh great! "s" modifier is exactly what i need. My fault i didn't check modifiers list before I wrote a question. Thanks Fab Sa for help!

Answer (score 1):

For parsing HTML I'd suggest reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php) and choosing a built in PHP extension.

If for some reason you *need* or *want* to use RegEx to do it you should know that:

- `preg_match()` is a **greedy** little bugger and it will try to eat your **anything** `(.*)` till it get's sick (meaning it hits recursion or backtracking limits). You change this with the **`U`** modifier<sup>1</sup>.
- the engine expects to be fed a *single line*. You change this with the **`m`** or **`s`** modifiers<sup>1</sup>.
- using your '**not a < character**' `([^<]*)` hack does a good job as it forces the engine to stop at the first **<** char, but will work **only if** the `<div>` doesn't contain other tags inside!

ref: <sup>1</sup> [PCRE Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)